# Insert query on Partitioned tables in Bigquery

Tags: hive, google-bigquery

I have some Insert queries written in hive to be migrated in Bigquery. 
For example:

```
insert into test.abc partition(yrmth) select * from test.xyz
```

In Bigquery, partition is only supported in `YYYYMMDD` format. I'm able to dump the data in partitioned table through BQ command line tool by loading `test.abc$20171125`.

How can I achieve the same using DML statements in Bigquery?

I have learnt that Legacy SQL doesn't support writing DML statements and Standard SQL doesn't support the table specifications like `test.abc$20171125` that is required for loading the data in corresponding partition.

Comment: See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36383555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct -  DML statements are not **yet** supported over partitioned tables.

Just do simple select `select * from test.xyz` with destination table `test.abc$20171125`. This is supported by Web UI, bq command line, API and any client of your choice

Check https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36383555 if you want to try `alpha release for column based partitioned tables` - `DML over partitioned tables` is part of it

Comment: Just a question: you cannot do the same by inserting values into _PARTITIONTIME column to create/append to the desired partition? Like:

    `INSERT INTO table 
        (_PARTITIONTIME, column1, ..)
    SELECT 
        TIMESTAMP('2018-04-05'),
        value1,
        ..
    FROM tableB`

Comment: check this - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#inserting_data